# JavaScript variable is "null"

Tags: javascript, jquery

on line 30 i am facing an issue with $.each(data.menu, function (). I am being told by the console that "data is null". can anyone explain whats going on? thanks

```js
function getFoodMenuData () {
    
    var url = 'http://localhost:8888/Tom_Carp_Final_Project/Chorizios/foodMenu.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        
        window.localStorage.setItem('choriziosMenu333', JSON.stringify(data));
        
 });
    
}

function showFoodMenuData () {
    
    var data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('choriziosMenu333'));
    
    var images = "";
        
    $.each(data.menu, function () {
 
       images += '<li class="list-group-item"><img style="width: 100%;" src= "' + this.url + '"></li>';
       images += '<li class="list-group-item">' + this.description + '</li>';
     
    });
        
    $('#foodMenu').append(images); 
     
}
    showFoodMenuData();
```

Comment: What is your retrieved json, did youve checked if local storage is working and set?

Comment: Is your data being stored in localStorage correctly after you call the `getFoodMenuData()` method?

Comment: @Tom have you checked whether the server is returning data?

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. You have to call `showFoodMenuData()` from inside the callback for the function to see the response from the server.

Comment: so where do i place showFoodMenuData(); im a noobie still trying to learn thanks

Comment: at the moment local storage is not working but it was working before i changed some code around. not sure where i ned to put the callback function

Comment: have you ever called getFoodMenuData() ? Also, you have to be sure the AJAX process is done. then call showFoodMenuData()

Comment: here is my new code. the console is showing the get request worked and its stored but its still not displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `getFoodMenuData()`, and then inside the callback for the asynchronous `$.getJSON`, call `showFoodMenuData()`.

```
function getFoodMenuData() {
  var url = 'http://localhost:8888/Tom_Carp_Final_Project/Chorizios/foodMenu.json';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('choriziosMenu333', JSON.stringify(data));
    showFoodMenuData(); // <--- call this inside the callback
  });
}

function showFoodMenuData() {
  var data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('choriziosMenu333'));
  var images = "";
  $.each(data.menu, function() {
    images += '<li class="list-group-item"><img style="width: 100%;" src= "' + this.url + '"></li>';
    images += '<li class="list-group-item">' + this.description + '</li>';
  });
  $('#foodMenu').append(images);
}

getFoodMenuData(); // <--- call this first
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use $ for the loop. I am not sure of the structure of the data you are receiving but you will probably need a nested loop to get all the data either way this should do the trick.

As a point the for in loop works great for objects. One reason is that the iterator is the key in the object. In this example if you console.log( ii ) inside the second loop you will see either name or url.

HTML

```
<ul></ul>
```

Javascript

```
var menu = {
    item1 : {
        name : "Food1",
        url  : "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/79/82/de/7982dec0cc2537665a5395ac18c2accb.jpg" 
    },
    item2 : {
        name : "Food2",
        url  : "http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1040796/images/o-CANADIAN-FOODS-facebook.jpg"
    }
};

$( document ).ready( function () {
    for ( var i in menu ) {
        for ( var ii in menu[ i ] ) {
            var elem = ii === "name" ? "<p>" + menu[ i ][ ii ] + "</p>" : "<img src="  + menu[ i ][ ii ] + " height='100px'/>"
            $( "ul" ).append( "<li>" + elem + "</li>" ); 
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dh3ozpxk/

Comment: this is my data: {
    
"menu": [
    {
        "url": "img/food_ex1.jpg",
        "description": "Pasta and Tomatoes"
    },
    {
        "url": "img/food_ex2.jpg",
        "description": "Stuffed Pasta"
    },
    {
        "url": "img/food_ex3.jpg",
        "description": "Penne Ala Vodka"
    },
    {
        "url": "img/food_ex4.jpg",
        "description": "Veggie Flatbread"
    },
    {
        "url": "img/food_ex5.jpg",
        "description": "Mushroom Pizza"
    }
 
   
]
    
}

Comment: btw i appreciate all of your help! trying this now

Comment: You are most welcome!
Check out this updated Fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/dh3ozpxk/1/

Comment: Used a regular loop for the array then the for in for the objects